# Pls explain how database works with django-rest-auth and get_user_model

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am going to use django-rest-auth for my project and add a connection to another database through the foreign key with the user's email. How can I describe it in my model, because at the moment my models.py file is empty and everything works fine. As I understand it, django-rest-auth uses the standard get_user_model function.

Sorry for such a stupid question, thanks

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Integrating Django with a legacy database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/legacy-databases/), it likely describes what you're looking for.

Comment: @Johan Wow, its exactly what i'm looking for! Thank you a lot!!

Comment: Cheers, no problem!